# Access data from other spring security filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is it possible to access the credentials and authorities granted by a previous filter in spring security?

Background:

I am developing a Java RESTful API using Spring and Spring Security with token-based authentication.
However, some calls have an additional protection with the user's password.

Currently I have my own implementation of a GenericFilterBean that filters out the token from the HTTP-Header and checks if it is present in the database. Depending on the permissions associated with this token, the user is granted different roles. The permissions are stored in the my database and can be retrieved with the token.

There are several calls in the API which need an additional authentication with the user's password.

I thought of creating a second custom filter that extractes the password from the header.
The problem with this approach is that I don't want to identify the user just by his password but rather by the user extracted from the the token in the first filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SecurityContextHolder` always holds the current authentication object. You can retrieve the authentication placed there by authentication filters by calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, which returns an object that has the methods `getAuthorities()`, `getCredentials()`, and `getPrincipal()`.

Comment: Of course! Thanks! I already use the SecurityContextHolder in my application, I just did not thought about accessing it in the filters too -.-